# Catching dependency injection errors in controllers in .NET Web Api

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have a simple C# Web Api project that provides a few restful endpoints.

Controller fatal server error handling/logging is generally well described by either using:

1. Implementing/overriding Application_Error method in Global.asax.cs

```
protected override void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       var ex = Server.GetLastError();
       _logger.Error("Unexpected error while initializing application", ex);
   }
```

2. Or by adding an exception handler filter:

`config.Filters.Add(new ExceptionHandlingAttribute());`

OR

`GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters.Add(new ExceptionHandlingAttribute());`

```
public class ExceptionHandlingAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
    {
        private static readonly ILog _logger = LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

        public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
        {
            _logger.Error("Unexpected error in API.", actionExecutedContext.Exception);

            throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
            {
                Content = new StringContent("An error occurred, please try again or contact the administrator."),
                ReasonPhrase = "Critical Exception"
            });
        }
    }
```

However, when an error occurs during instantiation of a controller due to a failure in dependency injection within the constructor of this code:

```
    public class DataController : ApiController
    {
        private readonly IDataService _dataService;

        public DataController(IDataService dataService)
        {
            _dataService = dataService;
        }

        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpGet]
        public IHttpActionResult GetSomeStuff()
        {
            return Ok(new AjaxResponse("somestuff"));
        }
```

none of the above methods catches the error. How can I catch those errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer myself which is the following.

One has to implement and override the IHttpControllerActivator interface on a GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services level (this is important as config.Services only deals with already instantiated controllers).

Here are some snippets:

Startup.cs

```
    // the following will make sure that any errors that happen within the constructor
    // of any controller due to dependency injection error will also get logged
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.Replace(typeof(IHttpControllerActivator),
              new ExceptionHandlingControllerActivator(                        
                 GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.GetHttpControllerActivator())
                    );
```

ExceptionHandlingControllerActivator.cs

```
    /// <summary>
    /// This class handles instantiation of every api controller. It handles and logs 
    /// any exception that occurs during instatiation of each controller, e.g. errors
    /// that can happen due to dependency injection.
    /// </summary>
    public class ExceptionHandlingControllerActivator : IHttpControllerActivator
    {
        private IHttpControllerActivator _concreteActivator;
        private static readonly ILog _logger = LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

        public ExceptionHandlingControllerActivator(IHttpControllerActivator concreteActivator)
        {
            _concreteActivator = concreteActivator;
        }

        public IHttpController Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)
        {
            try
            {
                return _concreteActivator.Create(request, controllerDescriptor, controllerType);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.Error("Internal server error occured while creating API controller " + controllerDescriptor.ControllerName, ex);

                throw new HttpResponseException(request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "Unexpected error while creating controller " + controllerDescriptor.ControllerName));
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is described very nicely in [this blog post](https://ruhul.wordpress.com/2014/09/05/how-to-handle-exceptions-globally-in-asp-net-webapi-2/). Excerpt to answer question below:

Create a class:

```
public class GlobalExceptionHandler : ExceptionHandler
{
    public async override Task HandleAsync(ExceptionHandlerContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // Access Exception
        // var exception = context.Exception;

        const string genericErrorMessage = &quot;An unexpected error occured&quot;;
        var response = context.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, 
            new
            { 
                Message = genericErrorMessage
            });

        response.Headers.Add(&quot;X-Error&quot;, genericErrorMessage);
        context.Result = new ResponseMessageResult(response);
    }
}
```

Then Register you exception handler as below from you application startup or owin setup as below:

```
public static class SetupFiltersExtensions
{
    public static IAppBuilder SetupFilters(this IAppBuilder builder, HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Services.Replace(typeof (IExceptionHandler), new GlobalExceptionHandler());

        return builder;
    }
}
```

As stated in his post, he isn't logging in the above method but prefers to do so through a `GlobalErrorLogger` as such:

```
public class GlobalErrorLogger : ExceptionLogger
{
    public override void Log(ExceptionLoggerContext context)
    {
        var exception = context.Exception;
        // Write your custom logging code here
    }
}
```

Registered as such:

```
public static class SetupFiltersExtensions
{
    public static IAppBuilder SetupFilters(this IAppBuilder builder, HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Services.Replace(typeof (IExceptionHandler), new GlobalExceptionHandler());
        config.Services.Add(typeof(IExceptionLogger), new GlobalErrorLogger());

        return builder;
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not actually solve the errors that occur DURING the instantiation of each controller. It only handles errors that happen within a method of a controller.

Comment: `GlobalExceptionFilter` wouldn't catch during instantiation as in your question. `GlobalExceptionHandler` should as stated in the post. I have used this technique successfully in projects like this [one](https://github.com/PdFramework/Logging/tree/master/NLog.Web.Http)